# Form reset using jQuery Validate plugin with Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I am using jQuery Validate to validate my form. And inside form have tag select, my select using `select2` jQuery. I have problem when I clear my from it's make my `select2` change required field. How to using validate with select2 work fine?

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//validate form
$(".form_required").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');     
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass('select2') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container'));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

$('.select2').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: ""
}).on("change", function (e) {
    $(this).valid();
});
});

function clear(){
   $("#myformHeader select").val('').trigger('change');
}
```

My HTML:

```
<form name="myformHeader" id="myformHeader" class="form-horizontal form_required">
    <select type="text" name="ddl" id="ddl" class="form-control select2" required>
       <!-- many option -->
    </select>
    <select type="text" name="ddl2" id="ddl2" class="form-control select2" required>
       <!-- many option -->
    </select>
    <button  type="button" onclick="clear()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

When click button reset show required like this. I don't want to show this for clear
[image]

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this sentence: *"I have problem when I clear my from it's make my select2 change required field"*

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Select2 as you'd have the same issue without it.  Triggering `.valid()` on a `required` field does not clear out the validation messages... it only reaffirms them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Select2 as you'd have the same issue without it.  Triggering `.valid()` on a `required` field does not clear out the validation messages... it only reaffirms them.

To clear the form of errors, then you need to use [the plugin's `.resetForm()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/):

```
$("#myformHeader").validate().resetForm()
```

Then to clear the form data, use [the JavaScript `.reset()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset):

```
document.getElementById("myformHeader").reset();

or

$("#myformHeader")[0].reset();
```

---

The button:

```
<button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    var form = $("#myformHeader");
    form.validate().resetForm();   // clear out the validation errors
    form[0].reset();               // clear out the form data
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to your select2 to be optional just remove its required attribute ;)

Otherwise, if you want to have a value or empty this should do the trick ;

Before doing .validate()

```
$.validator.addMethod("atLeastOneElement", (value, element, options) => {
 // check whatever you need and return boolean (true = valid)
});
```

Then add this to the validate({})

```
rules: {
    ddl: {
        atLeastOneElement: true
    }
}
```

dll is the name of your select not the id btw ( in your case the name and the id are the same )

Comment: I can't using like this. Because I hv many select. And attribute Name I,m use for different for other case

Comment: You mean you have several select2 using the same name but only some have to be validate??

Comment: Several select not using the same name.. I cannot using the same attribute name..

Comment: Just declare one rule per name
Unless you have 100 select2 ;)
rules: {
    ddl: {
        atLeastOneElement: true
    },
    ddl2: {
        atLeastOneElement: true
    }
}